# SharePoint Designer 2013: Call HTTP Web Service

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer

I have a workflow that freezes on the part where it's calling a web service. I debugged the service and found out that it's taking too long to execute before sending a response.

Is there a timeout in SPD that is being followed when waiting for a response from the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in SPD but definitely in SharePoint and IIS. By default these timeouts are usually set to 30 seconds.

EDIT:

I found the process of increasing the timeout [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680843(v=azure.10).aspx) - Nath

You can set the value only globally for your workflow host, but not for WF Manager scopes, for specific WFs or actions.

For example, if you want to increase the default value of 1 minute to 2 minutes:
Set-WFServiceConfiguration -ServiceUri https://UriOfYourWFService:12290 -Name WorkflowServiceMaxHttpResponseTime -Value 00:02:00

Comment: Thank you. I edited your answer to include a link for the steps for increasing the timeout.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for sharing and helping improve the answer.

Comment: @Nath: Instead of links it is always better to include a short example or text from the page you refer to. Links might be not available later.